# proof-verification: Do Carmo's Differential geometry of curves and surfaces, proposition 2-3-1.

Tags: differential-geometry, solution-verification, proof-explanation

In section 2-3 of Do Carmo's *Differential geometry of curves and surfaces*, proposition 1 states that:

> $S\subseteq\mathbb{R}^3$ is a regular surface. $U, V$ are two open
> sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$. $\vec{x}:U\to S$ and $\vec{y}: V\to S$ are two
> parametrizations. $p\in S$ and it is in the image of both $\vec{x}$,
> $\vec{y}$. Denote the intersection of the image of $\vec{x}$ and
> $\vec{y}$ by $W$. Then
> $h=\vec{x}^{-1}\circ\vec{y}:\vec{y}^{-1}(W)\to\vec{x}^{-1}(W)$ is
> differentiable and so is $h^{-1}$.

I am confused by the proof, the sketch of which is:

> Select $r\in\vec{y}^{-1}(W)$, $q=h(r)$. Let
> $\vec{x}(u,v)=(x(u,v),y(u,v),z(u,v))$. We may assume
> $J(\frac{x,y}{u,v})\ne 0$ at $q$.
>
> Construct $F:U\times{\mathbb{R}}\to\mathbb{R}^3$, $(u,v,t)\mapsto
>  (x(u,v),y(u,v),z(u,v)+t)$. Then $J(\frac{x,y,z}{u,v,t})\ne 0$ at $q$.
> Hence in $\mathbb{R}^3$ exists an open set $M$ containing $\vec{x}(q)$
> s.t. $F^{-1}$ exists and is differentiable on $M$. Select an open set
> in $V\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$ s.t. $\vec{y}(N)\subseteq M$. **The writer
> then says: for all $(u,v)\in N$, $h(u,v)=F^{-1}(\vec{y}(u,v))$, which
> implies $h$ is differentiable.**

But I do not understand that. $h(u,v)$ is in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $F^{-1}(\vec{y}(u,v))$ is in $\mathbb{R}^3$. I guess that the author meant:

> If $\vec{x}^{-1}\circ\vec{y}(u,v)=h(u,v)=(\tilde{u},\tilde{v})$, then
> $\vec{x}(\tilde{u},\tilde{v})=\vec{y}(u,v)$, and
> $F(\tilde{u},\tilde{v},0)=\vec{x}(\tilde{u},\tilde{v})=\vec{y}(u,v)$.
> Since $F$ has an inverse, the vector constituting the first two
> coordinates of $F^{-1}(\vec{y}(u,v))$ is equal to $h(u,v)$, which
> implies $h$ is differentiable.

Is this correct?